# Removing a spefic Row from MultiIndex Pandas Frame - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python/Pandas. Trying to remove a row in a multiIndex Pandas Frame but cant figure out the correct level/Index/axis.

The code is:

```
df = web.DataReader(['CJR-B.TO'], 'yahoo', start, end)
df_transposed = df.transpose()
df_new = df_transposed.copy()
print(df_new.head())
```

Output is:

```
Date                 2020-12-18  2020-12-21  2020-12-22  2020-12-23
Attributes Symbols                                                 
Adj Close  CJR-B.TO        4.24        4.17        4.12        4.21
Close      CJR-B.TO        4.24        4.17        4.12        4.21
High       CJR-B.TO        4.31        4.19        4.20        4.21
Low        CJR-B.TO        4.10        4.02        4.09        4.10
Open       CJR-B.TO        4.10        4.07        4.17        4.10
```

I have to remove the following row from the frame :

```
Adj Close  CJR-B.TO        4.24        4.17        4.12        4.21
```

I have tried different combinations of parameters using the following command but no success:

```
DataFrame.drop(self, labels=None, axis=0, index=None, columns=None, level=None, inplace=False, errors='raise')
```

The target is to remove that row and save the frame in a csv file. Writing to csv file was no issue, just got stuck in removing the particular row. Any help will truly be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can drop that row before making the transpose. In effect you have to drop the column 'Adj Close'

```py
df = web.DataReader(['CJR-B.TO'], 'yahoo', start, end)
df.drop('Adj Close', axis=1, inplace=True)
df_transposed = df.transpose()
df_new = df_transposed.copy()
print(df_new.head())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `query`:

```
df.query('Attributes != "Adj Close"')
```

Output:

```
                     2020-12-18  2020-12-21  2020-12-22  2020-12-23
Attributes Symbols                                                 
Close      CJR-B.TO        4.24        4.17        4.12        4.21
High       CJR-B.TO        4.31        4.19        4.20        4.21
Low        CJR-B.TO        4.10        4.02        4.09        4.10
Open       CJR-B.TO        4.10        4.07        4.17        4.10
```